# How do you delete a directory you don't own in an NFS directory you do?

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

There should be a simple answer to this, but I can't find it.

```
~me/work>ls -la
drwxrwxr-x  3  me       mygroup  .
drwxrwxr-x  3  me       mygroup  ..
drwxrwxr-x  3  me       mygroup  folder1
drwxr-xr-x  3  person2  mygroup  folder2
```

This is in my home directory, which is an automounted NFS.  Somebody in my group created folder2 in my home directory and then left for vacation.

I can't delete the folder... I can't move it... can't change permissions on it.  How can I get rid of it?  My sysadmin has no clue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking to your sysadmin just get him to run within the directory

```
su -c "rm -r folder\ 2"
```

Or

```
su -c "chown [me] folder\ 2"
```

where [me] is your username... and delete it yourself

I'll look into another way - but these will certainly work

Comment: Doesn't work as root on my local machine.  Does it have to be root on the NFS server?

Comment: if the no_root_squash option is missing from /etc/exports then yes

Comment: or you can become person2 on your local machine and then delete it

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to remove the entire parent directory (`~me/work`)?

If so, copy all but `folder2` elsewhere, and remove the parent.

Comment: I don't think this will work because you won't be able to remove the entire parent directory if you don't have write access to all of its contents

Comment: I can move the folders around all I want... I just can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delete this. Can't your sysadmin delete it for you with the root account?

Comment: I don't know that much about NFS.. and he doesn't either apparently.  Root on my machine doesn't help... still permission denied.  Would root on the NFS server be required?

Comment: Privileges are managed by the NFS server, so you have to be either `person2` or `root` on NFS server to remove that folder.

Comment: Or disable root squashing on the NFS server...